# Apache enable php 7

Tags: php, apache, php-7

I built custom php-7 for pthread

```
$ php -v
 PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: May 20 2016 14:04:16) ( ZTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

But running localhost/info.php with code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

outputs **PHP Version 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.3**

How do I enable PHP7 to Apache

Comment: what apache version?

Comment: its apache2 version and I have shared installation notes too

Answer (score 1):

You can check and run following commands to enable php 7 on your browser.

If you have php7 enabled in apache it should look something like

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep php
php7.0.conf
php7.0.load
```

If php7.0 is an availible mod you should be able to

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```